# How can we notify mixpanel to send push notification programatically in ios

Tags: ios

I have an app which is using Mixpanel. In that app I am using push notification. I could able to send the push notification manually to the registered devices list from Mixpanel profile.

My requirement is user can set reminder for persons who are in his phone book contact. Those persons should get the push notification who are using my app and accepted to recieve push notification. How can I do this if this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get any reply to this post. After that I asked to support Team. This is the reply to my question.

1. What is the use of People Analytics? Can it help to notify Mixpanel to send push notifications? if so how?

People Analytics is a platform that allows you to generate lists of user profiles in Mixpanel and compile unique attributes to it. For example, I created a profile for myself, where my favorite music is classical [here](http://note.io/1pHEYRd). I can then aggregate all users who's favorite music is classical, and send a targeted push notification to them. The goal with Mixpanel People Analytics is to help you deliver targeted notifications to your users. So it's definitely the right platform to help you send push notifications through! [Here's](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios#storing-user-profiles) how you start storing user profiles, and [here](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios#push-notifications) how is how you set up push notifications.

2. How can we send the reminder note to Mixpanel which will be send as push notification to the concerned person?

All through the UI! Through Mixpanel, you set up the push notification to have it look exactly how you want ([here](http://note.io/1pHFBdo)) and then you define the targeted criteria of users you'd like to reach.

3. How can we notify mixpanel to send push notification to the particular person ?

Once again, as long as you can identify those users through the unique attributes (for example, all users who's favorite music is classical) you can send them those notifications ([here](http://note.io/1pHFU85)).

Comment: Is it also possible to do it via API calls without the need for some admin to log in to mixpanel?

Comment: Exactly I want this functionality. but it is not possible till now. may be it will be available later

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel JQL API enables your to retrieve user device tokens via the properties `$ios_devices` and `$android_devices`. Using Apple APN and GCM endpoints, i guess your could push your own notifications via your own code with this (i've managed to retrieve the tokens, havent tried actually pushing my own way yet).